# jQuery on scroll always toggling to hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this jQuery code snippet to hide the menu on scroll down and reveal on scroll up:

```
var prev = 0;
var $window = $(window);
var nav = $('.nav');

$window.on('scroll', function(){
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    nav.toggleClass('hidden', scrollTop > prev);
    prev = scrollTop;
});
```

It works as expected but I only want it to kick in after the user scrolls 500px down the page.

I have wrapped the function in another function to achieve this result:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 500) {

        var prev = 0;
        var $window = $(window);
        var nav = $('.nav');

        $window.on('scroll', function(){
            var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
            nav.toggleClass('hidden', scrollTop > prev);
            prev = scrollTop;
        });

    }
});
```

However, with this added the toggle always reverts to class=hidden when scrolled up or down past 500px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic isn't quite right. You simply need to add the `if` condition within the current `scroll` handler. Try this:

```
var prev = 0;
var $window = $(window);
var nav = $('.nav');

$window.on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 500) {
    nav.toggleClass('hidden', scrollTop > prev);
  } else {
    nav.addClass('hidden');
  }
  prev = scrollTop; 
});
```

Note the addition of the `else` to cater for cases where the value jumps due to the renderer not being able to keep up with the scroll speed.

Comment: Thanks for that, your code didnt quite work as it always evaluated to hidden <500px (while I wanted it to be revealed by default) as such I changed 'nav.addClass('hidden');' in the else statement to '$('nav').removeClass('hidden');' and it seems to be working now. Thanks for your feedback. The only reamining issue is I'm getting the following warning on 'prev = scrollTop;' - "ScrollTop used out of scope". Any idea why?

Comment: I knew I'd get the add/remove class in the `else` the wrong way around :) Glad you got it working though. Apologies for the error, I updated the answer to fix that